# Are Haskell functions and data constructors have anything in common if they both have the same ending from the capital letter?

Tags: haskell

Let's imagine we have the following data definitions:

```
data Human = Age | Weight | Height
```

Now we define some function, which do something useful

```
getHeight :: Double -> String
getHeight a
  | a <= 165   = "Short"
  | a < 185    = "Average"
  | otherwise    = "Tall"
```

The question is: does Height and getHeight have anything in common at all?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're getting at, but the only answer has to be "no". `Height` is just a constructor for the `Human` type (one which takes no values, so it's a bit like a Boolean value like `True`), and `getHeight` doesn't involve the `Human` type at all. Did you mean for the `Height` constructor to take a `String` parameter and then have `getHeight` return a `Human` by doing eg. `otherwise = Height "Tall"`?

Comment: Well... no. Just because two things have similar names doesn't mean they're related. Your `Human` type also looks a bit sketchy, because it basically reads "A human is either age, or a human is weight, or a human is height" which doesn't make a whole lot of sense on the surface level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The names aren't related the way that you've written them.  However, if you defined your data type as:

`data Human = Human { age :: Double, height :: Double, weight :: Double }`

then you would get a height method for free:

```
let bob = Human 18 72 189
height bob    -- this will be 72
```

You might consider making your getHeight function more specific to take a Human rather than a double:

```
getHeight :: Human -> String
getHeight person 
  | height person <= 165 = "Short"
  | height person < 180  = "Average"
  | otherwise = "Tall"
```

Now the getHeight function *is* linked to the height that was defined as being an attribute of a Human, as opposed to simply being associated with an arbitrary double.